# I am using http.post to get a response, and setting my div [innerHTML]="response.html", but angular2 is removing javascript from the html page

Tags: angular, typescript

snippet from template

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="responseDiv" *ngIf="(response$ | async) as response">
<div class="col-sm-12" *ngIf="!response.status">
<div style="height: 800px; overflow: auto" [innerHTML]="response.html">
</div></div></div>
```

The div does not have the complete html, its stripped of important content. What do I do?

Edit: I mean, the HTML is complete, but does not display correctly. I think its missing JS.

Edit2: Sorry, I thought this was a simple example so did not paste my typescript. I cannot immediately post a plnkr example because the URL and body aren't something I can share. But the URL that I POST to, returns HTML, that I need to display. You see below my service:

```
this.http
      .post(url, body, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'text'
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
        const newResponse: HtmlContent = {
          html: response.body,
          fields: this.validationService.validate(response.body)
        };
        this.hopResponse$.next(newResponse);
      }, error => {
        const error_code = (error as HttpErrorResponse).status;
        console.log(error_code);
        this.hopResponse$.next(Object.assign({}, this.hopResponse, { status: 'error' }, {e_code : error_code }));
      });
```

And this is my component (I hope this does not raise more questions :):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HtmlContent} from '../../../app.interfaces';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {PaymentService} from '../../../services/payment.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hop-post-response',
  templateUrl: './post-response.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-response.component.scss']
})
export class HOPPostResponseComponent implements OnInit {

  response$: Observable<HtmlContent>;

  constructor(private paymentService: PaymentService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.response$ = this.paymentService.hopResponse$;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a plunker, I am totally confused with the snippet you attached. Means where's the JavaScript, what response you're getting from the POST req. So, need more info.

Comment: Added more code, can't paste to plnkr, maybe I will try another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're most likely seeing here is Angular's sanitization process at work. See [Angular Security](https://angular.io/guide/security) for more details of what happens. But it will remove `<script>` out of `innerHTML` for example.

There's way around it if you *trust* your input. For example, you can use the [`someSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(response.html)`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to mark the value as trusted and not have `innerHTML` strip out the troublesome parts.

If you don't trust the input, then this is a very dangerous thing to do. You should use an `iframe` to hold the received content. You'll not get any `innerHTML`-like issues and there'll be a browser enforced separation between your context and the `iframe`'s one, so whatever malicious script gets executed inside it won't be able to touch you.